# align-self property in flexbox is not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to understand flex box:
I want to make the “first” block stretched to match the full width of the browser, and the ”second” block of fixed size and aligned to left.

So I used `align-items: flex-end` in the parent(`<html>`) and tried to stretch the first block using `align-self: stretch` in the ”first” block.

This is not working. Both of them are aligned to the left.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }

      #first {
        align-self:stretch;
        background-color: red;
        border: 3px solid black;
      }

      #second {
        background-color:green;
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 3px solid yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="first">This is first</div>
    <div id="second">This is second</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So the problem is that you've got the `<html>` node as a flex container, and the `<body>` node (its child) is the one and only flex item.

Currently, `align-self:stretch` on `#first` is ignored, because that property only applies to flex items, and `#first` is *not* a flex item (the way you have things set up right now).

To get what you want, you need to make the `<body>` node a flex container, *not* the `<html>` node.  So, just change your first style rule to apply to `body{` instead of `html{`

(Also, if you want #second to be aligned to the left, you need `flex-start`, not `flex-end`. The left edge is the `flex-start` horizontal edge, generally.)

Comment: @dholbert what do u mean by "generally" ? :D

Comment: (I mean you could (for example) flip which edge is the `flex-start` edge by using `direction: rtl`, or use the more-complex `writing-mode` property to make text & flex containers vertical by default.  If you're not using those properties, then a flex container with `flex-direction: row` will have its flex-start edge at the left.)

Answer (score 3):

Add flex:1 to #first

Remove justify-content: flex-start; and align-items: flex-end; from html

See example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vifIr