# align-self property isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a bar graph component that I want to be able to easily scale up and down depending on the size of data set. Hence `flex`.

When applying `align-self: stretch;` to the `.bar.value` selectors it isn't stretching to the height of the parent container.

I've looked at similar questions around on Stack to do with `align-self: stretch;` but none seem to be experiencing the issue for the same reason.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
.bar.graph.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.bar.graph.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
}
.bar.value {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar graph container">
  <div class="bar value">
  </div>
  <div class="bar value">
  </div>
  <div class="bar value">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [align-self property in flexbox is not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053156/align-self-property-in-flexbox-is-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @prasad, but I am not sure how the solution supplied applies in this scenario.

Comment: your container has zero height... another is that `align-self:stretch` is the default style and it applies even if you don't give it...

Comment: @kukkuz I have defined it with `::after` as I need true square for my component and am achieving it with the help of `padding-top`. Reckon this i what is impacting the `flex` container?

Comment: that would not affter the flexbox...`body` has `height` 0... so `container` has 0 too... try `height: 100vh` for the `container` and remove `padding-top` in `::after`... is it as expected now?